# Hover on a styled component without wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

So I have this:

```
const Link = styled.a`
    color: blue;
`;

<Wrapper>
    <Link href="/">Hover Change</Link>
<Wrapper>
```

I want to put a hover effect on just the Link element to change the color to white.  Any other docs I have seen would have me put a hover call when I call Link:

```
const Wrapper=styled.div`
    &:hover ${Link}: white;
';
<Wrapper>
    <Link href="/">Hover Me</Link>
<Wrapper>
```

How do I place the a:hover in the styling for the Link component?

Answer (score 18):

@psion have you checked something like the following code:

```
const Link = styled.a`
  color: blue;

  &:hover {
    color: white;
  }
`;

<Link href="/">Hover Change</Link>
```

Comment: This is actually the right approach, do the styling directly on the component, do not nest styles. The main reason to use sc is to be able to reuse the components everywhere. A Link that has a nested style just works in this context and therefore is not easily reusable.